# brownian motion continuous property

Tags: brownian-motion

In Stein and Shakarchi's functional analysis,

> Brownian motion $B_t$ is defined in terms of a probability space $(\Omega, P)$ with $P$ its probability measure and $\omega$ denoting a typical point in $\Omega$. We suppose that for each $t$, $0 \le t < \infty$, the function $B_t$ is defined on $\Omega$ and takes the values in $\mathbb{R}^d$. The Brownian motion process $B_t = B_t(\omega)$ satisfy $B_0(\omega) = 0$ almost everywhere and
>
> 1. The increments are independent.
> 2. The increment $B_{t+h} - B_t$ are Gaussian with covariance $hI$ and mean zero for each $0 \le t < \infty$.
> 3. For almost every $\omega \in \Omega$, the path $t \mapsto B_t(\omega)$ is continuous for $0 \le t < \infty$
>
> Now it will turn out that this process can be realized in a canoncial way in terms of a natural choice of the probability space $\Omega$. This probability space, denoted by $\mathcal{P}$, is the space of continuous paths in $\mathcal{R}^d$ starting at the origin: it consists of the continuous functions $t \mapsto p(t)$ from $[0, \infty)$ to $\mathcal{R}^d$ with $p(0) = 0$.
>
> Since, by assumption 3, for almost every $\omega \in \Omega$ the function $t \mapsto B_t(\omega)$ is such a continuous path, we get an inclusion $i : \Omega \to \mathcal{P}$ and then the probability measure $P$ gives us, as we will see, a corresponding measure $W$ (the "Wiener measure") on $\mathcal{P}$.

The first two are straightforward. The third property however confuses me slightly. It seems like we are $t \mapsto B_t(\omega)$ is continuous for a fixed $\omega \in \Omega$. Does that mean if we have $\omega_1, \omega_2 \in \Omega$, $\begin{cases} B_t(\omega_1) \quad \text{ if } 0 \le t \le N \\ B_t(\omega_2) \quad \text{ if } t > N \end{cases}$ is not necessarily continuous?

EDIT:
So if I understood this correctly, $(\Omega, P)$ is not a product space but just an ordinary sample space with measure $P$. Now, we can define $\mathcal{P} := \{ p \in \mathbf{C}([0, \infty)): p(0) = 0\}$. Since by assumption 3, for any fixed $\omega \in \Omega$, $t\mapsto B_t(\omega)$ is continuous, we can get a new mapping $i : \Omega \to \mathcal{P}$, i.e, for any fixed $\omega$, there is a corresponding continuous function $p$. However, what confuses me is, again, the fixed $\omega$. If $\omega$ is fixed, wouldn't $B_t(\omega)$ be a constant function for all $t$?

Comment: You are right. The stochastic process you defined would not be continuous at $ t = N $ if $ \omega_1 \neq \omega_2 $.

Comment: @joy Hmm I see. If we fix $\omega$, is $t \mapsto B_t(\omega)$ not a constant function because of the second property where increments are gaussian?

Comment: In the most simple case you have $Ω=\{f\in C([0,\infty)):f(0)=0\}$ and $B_t(ω)=ω(t)$. With this realization the last property is trivial. In other constructions of BM it is less so.

Comment: For fixed $ \omega $, not only $ t \mapsto B_t(\omega) $ is not a constant function, but it is [nowhere differentiable](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2009/REUPapers/McKnight.pdf) with probability 1.

Comment: @joy could you explain why it is not a constant function?

Comment: For a constant function, say $ f(t) = c $, the increment $ f(t) - f(s) = 0 $ for all $ s\le t $. Since for a Brownian motion the increments follow Gaussian distributions, the Brownian path $ t\mapsto B_t(\omega) $ cannot be a constant function with probability 1.

Answer (score 1):

After reading all the insightful comments, I think I finally understand what the book is trying to say. I think these are the subtle points that I often miss when going through math textbooks. I initially assumed that $\Omega$ is the space of continuous functions. While this may be the most intuitive and canonical way of constructing a Brownian motion, it doesn't necessarily have to be this way.

In fact, later in the book, it says that

> In general it is useful to think of this process as either in terms of an abstract realization $B_t$ on $(\Omega, P)$ satisfying conditions B-1, B-2, and B-3, or its concrete realization on $(\mathcal{P}, W)$ with $W$ the Wiener measure, given in terms of $B_t(\omega) = p(t)$, where $\omega$ is identified with $p$.

So the continuity property of a Brownian motion is with regard to a fixed $\omega \in \Omega$. If we set $\Omega = C([0, \infty))$ and $B_t = \omega(t)$ (the book uses $p$ instead of $\omega$ and $\mathcal{P}$ instead of $\Omega$), we get a more intuitive construction process.

Answer (score 0):

I think your confusion relates to the notion of fixing $\omega \in \Omega.$ It should be understand that $\Omega$ is really $\Omega \times [0,\infty)$ in this case. Fixing $\omega \in \Omega$ means to fix a sequence of $\omega$ in $\Omega \times [0,\infty)$, which is what is meant by fixing a path.

Comment: when you wrote $\Omega \times [0, \infty)$, are you referring to a product space? i.e., $\Omega \times \Omega \times ...$?

Comment: Yes exactly, the product of $\Omega$ and the time set.

Comment: As nothing was said about $Ω$, speculations about its inner structure and what it is not are not possible. One might find one interpretation where $Ω=\Bbb R^{[0,\infty)}$, where the probability measure ensures that non-continuous paths become a null-set.